# Azure data factory pagination doesn't work

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am working on a pipeline which executes oAuth2 flow in order to access [REST API json data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/develop/get-invoice-unbilled-consumption-lineitems#rest-request). Once I have the bearer token I am executing a request which returns the following structure:

[image]

As you can see, since the response is quite large, there's paging enabled and as part of the response I get a link to the next page. In order to get to that resource I need to also present **MS-ContinuationToken** in the headers. So, this is how I basically do it in the config of the **Copy activity** that I use to get the data from the REST endpoint:

[image]

and the issue here is that I only get the first 2000 rows and the next page(s) don't seem to be visited at all. Pipeline executes successfully and only the first 2000 items are fetched.

**NOTE**: *continuationToken* and *links.next.headers.value* have the exact same values from the initial response.

Comment: In your screenshot, `headers` is an array so presumably you'd need $['links']['next']['headers'][0]['value'], otherwise you'll get null and the pagination won't work.  But then if it's the same value in each call, could you not just get it from $['continuationToken']?

Comment: I did the same but the issue was that the response from CSP and respectively the url to the next page doesn't contain the version (v1 in my case). And it is not possible to dynamically assign that through the pagination rules. I think partnercenter needs to be notified about that.

Comment: Is that just a relative url then?

Comment: @JasonWelch Yes. And it doesn't include the 'v1' in front of it which is important part.

Comment: what is configured as the url in your dataset?  starting your url with / sounds like absolute not relative url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you fix the other issue you’ll have an issue with the “next” URL not including “v1”. This is a known issue in the partner center api team. I’ve escalated it pretty high. But they don’t want to break backwards compatibility by changing the “next” URI to include the v1 or to be relative. They are considering other options but I wouldn’t hold your breath.

I would ditch the idea of using data factory and instead write a .NET console app using the partner center SDK

(You might think to paginate manually with loops etc but the Copy activity doesn’t return eg the http headers, so you will need a complex set up to somehow store the data in a data store and be able to look up the last page in order to get the continuation token. I couldn’t figure it out)

Comment: As a workaround, you can:
1) Create an Azure Function Proxy, setting the Route template to "/invoices/{*restOfPath}" and backend URL to "https :// api.partnercenter.microsoft.com/v1/invoices/{restOfPath}"
2) Use the endpoint of your Azure Function in ADF, https://<myfunctionapp>.azurewebsites.net/invoices to avoid the "/v1" issue